# unicode for arrow keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I am trying to make a game where you can instantly have the user's input be transmitted to the computer instead of having to press `enter` every time. I know how to do that, but I cannot seem to find the unicode number for the arrow keys. Is there unicode for that, or am I just going to be stuck with wasd?

```
class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys
    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt
    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()
class _Getch:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()
    def __call__(self): return self.impl()
getch = Getch()
```

I using `getch.impl()` as a trial-or-error input, as in if there's a key being pressed when the function is called, it returns that key, and moves on. If there's no key being pressed, it just moves on.
I'm using Python 2.7.10

Comment: If you're trying to handle keyboard events or key states, what you want isn't Unicode. Keyboards don't work that way. Check the documentation for whatever it is you're using to handle keyboard input. If you're using something that works in terms of characters instead of keyboard keys, you'll need to use something else.

Comment: "*I know how to do that*" - can you tell us how you do that? Once we know what you've done so far, we can describe what to do about arrow keys.

Comment: You could use Unicode arrow glyphs with the codepoints U+2190 through U+2193 which correspond, respectively, to the leftwards, upwards, rightwards, and downwards arrows (←, ↑, ↓, →). However your code using `msvcrt` is incorrect. See @Terry Jan Reedy's answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the relevant doc for msvcrt.

> msvcrt.kbhit()
>
> Return true if a keypress is waiting to be read.
>
> msvcrt.getch()
>
> Read a keypress and return the resulting character as a byte string. Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed. If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return '\000' or '\xe0'; the next call will return the keycode. The Control-C keypress cannot be read with this function.

Notice that getch blocks and requires two calls for special function keys, which include arrow keys (they initially return `b'\xe0`).

Then use sys.platform and write two versions of a get_arrow function.

```
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import msvcrt as ms
    d = {b'H': 'up', b'K': 'lt', b'P': 'dn', b'M': 'rt'}
    def get_arrow():
        if ms.kbhit() and ms.getch() == b'\xe0':
            return d.get(ms.getch(), None)
        else:
            return None
else:  # unix
...
```

I experimentally determined the mapping of keys to codes with the following code. ( This will not work when run in IDLE and maybe not in other GUI frameworks, as getch conflicts with GUI handling of the keyboard.)

```
>>> import msvcrt as ms
>>> for i in range(8): print(ms.getch())
...
b'\xe0'
b'H'
b'\xe0'
b'K'
b'\xe0'
b'P'
b'\xe0'
b'M'
```

I tested the function on Windows with

```
while True:
    dir = get_arrow()
    if dir: print(dir)
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question which suggests the OP is using Windows.  Do you know something which is not stated?

Comment: @wallyk: The fact that the OP has code using the `msvcrt` module at least indicates they want the code to run on Windows. So, no, it wasn't explicitly stated.

Comment: Terry: Good point, but I think to answer the OP's question, you would need to map the `getch()` values to matching Unicode values for the arrow characters—as well as do something that gives the same results in Unix mode.

Comment: @martineau:  You are correct.  After I saw the Unix case, I stopped looking at the details which are indeed there to support Winders.

Comment: @wallyk I wrote the (tested) Windows version of how to convert getch() to something usable because I could.  I have no idea what `ch` in the unix code will be for the different keys.  I did provide the code I used to discover exactly what getch returns for each.

Comment: @martineau There are no 'unicode' values for the various special keys on a keyboard.  I arbitrarily mapped the differentiating bytes for Windows getch to the unicode strings `up`, `lt`, `dn`, and `rt`.  Ty can replace them with anything s/he wants.  I left it to Ty or anyone else with a *nix and OSX machines to write current *nix and OSX versions.   Ty's code is apparently from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/, 13 years ago.  See comments thereon.

Comment: Terry: I can read and therefore know exactly what your code is (and isn't) doing. There _are_ Unicode values that can be used to represent these special keyboard keys, and they could be used for both Windows and Unix implementations (with the appropriate coding).

Comment: @martineau Since you looked up the unicode arrow glyphs, those could be used in dict d instead.  But unless key_arrow is going to be printed, it does not matter, at long as the caller expects what whatever is returned.  If one used tkinter events, which I consider a viable option, event.keysym would be strings 'Up', 'Down', 'Left', or 'Right'.